# Error occuring while using useRef in Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to learn nextjs13 and typescript. I imported the the useRef hook and its giving me an error.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"

export const useDraw = () => {

   const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        
    }, [])

    return { canvasRef }
}
```

```
import { FC } from "react"
import { useDraw } from "../hooks/useDraw"

interface pageProps{}

const page: FC<pageProps> = ({}) => {
  const { canvasRef } = useDraw()
  return <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-white flex justify-center items-center">
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={750} height={750} className="border border-black rounded"/>
  </div>
}

export default page
```

Answer (score 6):

NextJS now differentiates b/w server components and client components.

All components inside the app directory are React Server Components by default. To use `useRef` you have to mark the component as client side.

On the file where you are using `useRef`, add `'use client'` at the beginning of your code. This will ensure the component can run on client side.

```js
'use client';

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
..
```

I think where you are using the `useDraw` hook could also need this `use client` declaration.

Reference:

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components

Comment: Adding 'use client'; the beginning of my code works. Thank you so much for your help and for attaching the beta documentation.