# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') with a library built with vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vite

I build my library with the following configuration

`src/components/index.js`

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'

export function Foo() {
  const ref = useRef()

  return <div ref={ref}>Hi!</div>
}
```

`vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { resolve } from 'node:path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve('src', 'components/index.js'),
      // other stuff
    },
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/foo.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/foo.umd.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // some dev depencencies
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I tested my library inside a simple nextjs application:

```json
{
  "name": "example-nextjs-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "link:../../foo",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     // some dev depencencies
  }
}
```

Somewhere in my application

```js
import { Foo } from 'foo'

export function Header() {
  return <Foo />
}
```

Inside my library, I installed the dependencies using `pnpm install` and build it `pnpm run build`.
After that, inside my application, I also install using `pnpm install` and run it using `pnpm run dev`.

Navigating the page where I use my library, I got a runtime error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')`
I don't know the reason.

How can I fix my issue?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74497570/11233049

Also ensure you run a valid `pnpm install` command to install all your dependencies, 'cause maybe a typo error but you said you ran `npnpm install`.

Comment: tried to put 'use client' in different locations (inside my component, inside a  wrapper of my component), but none of them works.
I fixed also the typo, thanks.